# Gnuplot stats does not work as expected: max value not right

Tags: csv, statistics, command, gnuplot

Assuming to have the following 4 datasets:

**a.csv**

```
1,1
2,3
3,5
5,6
6,9
7,9
8,10
9,12
10,13
```

**b.csv**

```
1,1
2,5
3,10
5,15
6,20
7,25
8,30
9,35
10,40
```

**c.csv**

```
1,1
2,10
3,100
5,1000
6,2000
7,5000
8,10000
9,20000
10,50000
```

**d.csv**

```
1,1
2,20
3,300
5,5000
6,9000
7,10000
8,15000
9,30000
10,100000
```

In Gnuplot I've tried to run the command **stats** on each of them to get the maximum value for *x* and *y* (i.e., columns *1* and *2*) and to set the corresponding **xrange** & **yrange**. Unfortunately, the result is not the one I've expected.

Here is the full script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot
set terminal latex
set term pngcairo enhanced size 1500,800
set output 'plot.png'
set multiplot layout 2,2
set xlabel 't' font ',16'
set ylabel '#pkt' font ',16'
set grid xtics lt 0 lw 1 lc rgb "#333333"
set grid ytics lt 0 lw 1 lc rgb "#333333"
set xtics font ',14'
set ytics font ',14'
set key font ',12'
set title font ',20'
set datafile separator ','
###
set title '(a)'
stats "a.csv" using 1:2 name "a"
set xrange [0:a_max_x]
set yrange [0:a_max_y+a_max_y*0.5]
plot "a.csv" using 1:2 title 'v1' with lines linewidth 3 linecolor rgb 'blue'
###
set title '(b)'
stats "b.csv" using 1:2 name "b"
set xrange [0:b_max_x]
set yrange [0:b_max_y+b_max_y*0.5]
plot "b.csv" using 1:2 title 'v1' with lines linewidth 3 linecolor rgb 'blue'
###
set title '(c)'
stats "c.csv" using 1:2 name "c"
set xrange [0:c_max_x]
set yrange [0:c_max_y+c_max_y*0.5]
plot "c.csv" using 1:2 title 'v1' with lines linewidth 3 linecolor rgb 'blue'
###
set title '(d)'
stats "d.csv" using 1:2 name "d"
set xrange [0:d_max_x]
set yrange [0:d_max_y+d_max_y*0.5]
plot "d.csv" using 1:2 title 'v1' with lines linewidth 3 linecolor rgb 'blue'
###
unset multiplot
```

and the result:

[image]

As you can see, maximum values in the plots *b*, *c* and *d* are not correct. Indeed, the verbose output of stats returns:

```
[...]
Maximum:      10.0000 [8]       13.0000 [8]
[...]
Maximum:      5.0000 [3]       15.0000 [3]
[...]
Maximum:      2.0000 [1]       10.0000 [1]
[...]
Maximum:      1.0000 [0]        1.0000 [0]
[...]
```

Apparently, only stats for the plot *a* is right. Is there anything wrong in my script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need you reinitialize `xrange` and `yrange` after setting them each time, because otherwise `stats` finds some of you points outside the range you have previously set and does not take them into account. It's the last line below:

```
set title '(a)'
stats "a.csv" using 1:2 name "a"
set xrange [0:a_max_x]
set yrange [0:a_max_y+a_max_y*0.5]
plot "a.csv" using 1:2 title 'v1' with lines linewidth 3 linecolor rgb 'blue'
set xrange [*:*] ; set yrange [*:*] # <--- This line after each plot will fix your issue
```

Comment: Right, or one could use `stats [*:*][*:*] ...` in order to ignore the currently set ranges. Using ranges with `stats` is supported, although not documented, see http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/patches/672/

Answer (score 2):

In your case there is no need to use `stats` in order to set the ranges.

Your requirements are:

1. Use tight limits for the `xrange` and the `yrange`. You get this with `set autoscale fix`.
2. Extend the maximum of the `yrange` by 50%. That is achieved with `set offsets 0,0,graph 0.5,0`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot
set term pngcairo enhanced size 1500,800
set output 'plot.png'

set multiplot layout 2,2
set xlabel 't' font ',16'
set ylabel '#pkt' font ',16'

set grid xtics ytics lt 0 lw 1 lc rgb "#333333"

set tics font ',14'
set key font ',12'
set title font ',20'
set datafile separator ','

set style data lines
set style line 1 linewidth 3 linecolor rgb 'blue'
###

set title '(a)'
set autoscale fix
set offset 0,0,graph 0.5,0
plot "a.csv" using 1:2 title 'v1' linestyle 1

###
set title '(b)'
plot "b.csv" using 1:2 title 'v1' linestyle 1
###
set title '(c)'
plot "c.csv" using 1:2 title 'v1' linestyle 1
###
set title '(d)'
plot "d.csv" using 1:2 title 'v1' linestyle 1
###
unset multiplot
```

[image]

One further comment: If you're going to use a LaTeX-based terminal for your actual image, don't use `latex`, but rather `epslatex`, `cairolatex`, `context` or `lua tikz`, which are all much better regarding the supported features and quality.